# Exposing hangfire without auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Is there a way to expose Hangfire in IIS without having to configure authorization?

In this specific case the dashboard should be open, but when accessing it (not in debug) it returns a 401 code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should be able to write a custom implementation of `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter` as described [in the documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html?highlight=authentication#configuring-authorization). Be aware that the default is only local requests to the dashboard are allowed. **It's also recommended that you really use authorization and do not publish unauthorized dashboards as it contains sensitive information.**

If you still want to do it, try:

*Custom DashboardAuthorizationFilter*

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Use it in the configuration of hangfire*

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new [] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

Comment: Hi. I have a project that needed to be publish into Azure and I try your way but it's still failed.

Comment: @FaizEming Maybe you should create a new question and provide more information.

Comment: I did. I have different code method that I have stumble on Google and those code is outdated. I asked and nobody giving reply still. If you have free time, perhaps you can provide your time reading it help me, please.

Comment: @FaizEming A link would be helpful ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702161/how-can-i-public-hangfire-dashboard-for-custom-web-page