# How can I publish Hangfire Dashboard for a custom web page?

Tags: hangfire

I know that Hangfire set their dashboard to local only for security purposes. Then if I want to open it in a custom domain, I have to set the authorization for it. I have followed the *Configuring Authorization* guide but I don't understand what do I have to write inside `app.UseCookieAuthentication(…)`.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{

});
```

It returns me an error of

> Can't find namespace for CookieAuthenticationOptions

This code might be deprecated and does not work. All the topics about this are from a few years ago, so I don't know what they have updated from then on. Also in the mean time I want this to be open for all so I don't really need to set authentication for any role.

Comment: Configuring the authentication of your app is something different to configuring who may access the hangfire dashboard. The code snipped you included seems to be the part where you want to configure the authentication of the entire application. By the way, what application type are you building? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP.NET Core. At the moment I just want to public access to hangfire dashboard in Azure. I don't really need to have any authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exposing hangfire without auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162287/exposing-hangfire-without-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked in comments comments, if you want to set up public access to your dashboard without app running at localhost, you need to add custom `DashboardAuthorizationFilter` which will always return true (authorize anybody to gain access).

To do this create your filter as follows:

`using Hangfire.Dashboard;`

```
namespace your.app.namespace
{
    public class PassThroughDashboardAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context) => true;
    }
}
```

and then add it to your configuration:

```
        app.UseHangfireDashboard(options: new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new List<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>(){ new PassThroughDashboardAuthorizationFilter() },
            IsReadOnlyFunc = context => false // according to your needs
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, it's work. I just forget to change my connection :D